# Magento2 - UPS Saturday Ground Delivery

Tags: magento2, ups

Does anyone know how to integrate UPS Saturday Ground into Magento 2? I came across a **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628104/saturday-delivery-option-ups-extension-magento)** for Magento 1, but not **Magento 2.**

I am having issues making the Magento 2 UPS module work like the module from the link above.

Comment: Which issues do you encounter? Maybe you can show some code of what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Have you been in contact with UPS at all?  Have you got the latest version of the extension?